# serviceNow REST API sysparm_query fields that are not null

Tags: servicenow

`sysparm_query`  for rows that only have data in a specified column

For example:
I want data for incidents that are active and have a business application defined

`sysparm_query=active=true^`??????

Comment: Please post your question and what you have tried.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, was not able to find ISNOTEMPTY in the documentation.  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the column name for "Business Application" is `u_business_application`:
`sysparm_query=incident=true^u_business_applicationISNOTEMPTY`